# Adding image dynamically into Quote pdf

Tags: apex, lightning, content

We have a requirement to add Image that's associated to Quote as Salesforce file into Quote pdf. (we aren't using CPQ) Using formula field we can display image if its available as static resource. Following steps in below link, I tried to upload image into Library and used URL of Content document in formula field but it's showing broken image. So is it even possible?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385501&type=1

Formula field : IMAGE("xxxx/06952000001kHAn?retUrl=%2F_ui%2Fcore%2Fchatter%2Ffiles%2FFileTabPage", "pbs", 100,100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing a broken image in your formula field is because the URL of the content document that you are using is not a valid image URL. The URL that you are using is the URL of the **file preview page**, not the **actual image file**. To get the correct image URL, you need to do the following steps:

- Go to the library where you uploaded your image and click on the image file name to open the file preview page.
- Right-click on the image and select **"Copy image address"** or **"Copy image location"** depending on your browser. This will copy the image URL to your clipboard. The image URL should look something like this:

> **"/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Png&versionId=0680o00000eAuJs&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05T0o000024PkeP/icon.png"**

- Paste the image URL into your formula field using the IMAGE function. For example, you can use this formula:

> IMAGE("/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Png&versionId=0680o00000eAuJs&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05T0o000024PkeP/icon.png", "pbs", 100, 100)

This should display the image from the library in your formula field.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, thats exactly was the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, do you know if we can dynamically get the image address in Apex? Basically, whenever we upload image file on a Quote record, I need to add that into a library and save the image address into a custom field which will be referred by my Image formula field.